# why optimizer in Oracle database does not use index?

Tags: oracle, index, join, optimization, select

when I execute following queries see completely different result where is problem?

here I execute a simple select query which takes a few seconds to complete:

```
SELECT * FROM
        PRODUCTION.VERY_SMALL_TABLE L
        INNER JOIN PRODUCTION.BIG_PARTITIONED_TABLE_WITH_LOCAL_INDEX R
        on R.ID_1 = L.ID or R.ID_2 = L.ID
```

and its execution plan is:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                            | Name                                                   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                     |                                                        |    72M|  9554M|    11M  (1)| 00:07:16 |       |       |
|   1 |  VIEW                                | VW_ORE_65071C6B                                        |    72M|  9554M|    11M  (1)| 00:07:16 |       |       |
|   2 |   UNION-ALL                          |                                                        |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                      |                                                        |    50M|  6821M|  6056K  (1)| 00:03:57 |       |       |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                     |                                                        |    50M|  6821M|  6056K  (1)| 00:03:57 |       |       |
|   5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL               | VERY_SMALL_TABLE                                       |     7 |    98 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   6 |      PARTITION RANGE ALL             |                                                        |  7246K|       |   621   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |1048575|
|*  7 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN               | ID_2_INDX                                              |  7246K|       |   621   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |1048575|
|   8 |     TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID| BIG_PARTITIONED_TABLE_WITH_LOCAL_INDEX                 |  7246K|   877M|   865K  (1)| 00:00:34 |     1 |     1 |
|   9 |    NESTED LOOPS                      |                                                        |    21M|  2870M|  5097K  (1)| 00:03:20 |       |       |
|  10 |     NESTED LOOPS                     |                                                        |    42M|  2870M|  5097K  (1)| 00:03:20 |       |       |
|  11 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL               | VERY_SMALL_TABLE                                       |     7 |    98 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|  12 |      PARTITION RANGE ALL             |                                                        |  6098K|       |   621   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |1048575|
|* 13 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN               | ID_1_INDX                                              |  6098K|       |   621   (0)| 00:00:01 |     1 |1048575|
|* 14 |     TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID| BIG_PARTITIONED_TABLE_WITH_LOCAL_INDEX                 |  3049K|   369M|   728K  (1)| 00:00:29 |     1 |     1 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

but when I want to use above query to create a table like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE DUMMY_SCHEMA.DUMMY_TABLE AS
    (SELECT * FROM
        PRODUCTION.VERY_SMALL_TABLE L
        INNER JOIN PRODUCTION.BIG_PARTITIONED_TABLE_WITH_LOCAL_INDEX R
        on R.ID_1 = L.ID or R.ID_2 = L.ID);
```

execution plan changes to this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name                                      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | CREATE TABLE STATEMENT |                                           |   222G|    28T|  1971M  (1)| 21:23:21 |       |       |
|   1 |  LOAD AS SELECT        | DUMMY_TABLE                               |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS         |                                           |   222G|    28T|  1200M  (1)| 13:01:53 |       |       |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL   | VERY_SMALL_TABLE                          |     7 |    98 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   4 |    PARTITION RANGE ALL |                                           |    31G|  3756G|   171M  (1)| 01:51:42 |     1 |1048575|
|*  5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL  | BIG_PARTITIONED_TABLE_WITH_LOCAL_INDEX    |    31G|  3756G|   171M  (1)| 01:51:42 |     1 |1048575|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and create table query takes too too long to complete !!

Comment: "takes a few seconds to complete"?  The plan estimates it will take 7 minutes to select 72 million rows. Which is correct, you or the optimizer?

Comment: "create table query takes too too long to complete"  Do you get an error or did you cancel it?

Comment: I execute first query which is select and it takes only 172 ms to complete (in Datagrip of course which returns first 500 rows) I change Datagrip setting to bring back all result and it takes 3 min

Comment: In create table query, last time 4 hours passed and we have no output it just executing with no error

Comment: How many rows did datagrip retrieve?  Oracle version? Are the table statistics up to date?

Comment: Can you try the create table with a "first_rows" hint added to the select?

Comment: Datagrip retreived 7314 rows.  I execute create table with "first_rows" hint everything worked correctly.

Comment: what can I do to Oracle works correctly without hint. Thank you for your consideration

Comment: what can I do to Oracle works correctly without hint? do you have a solution?  @GerardH.Pille

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a first row hint, that way oracle may respond the same way as to the datagrip query.

```
CREATE TABLE DUMMY_SCHEMA.DUMMY_TABLE AS
    (SELECT /*+ first_rows */ * FROM
        PRODUCTION.VERY_SMALL_TABLE L
        INNER JOIN PRODUCTION.BIG_PARTITIONED_TABLE_WITH_LOCAL_INDEX R
        on R.ID_1 = L.ID or R.ID_2 = L.ID);
```

As an alternative you could analyze your tables, so that the optimizer can use up to date statistics.

Answer (score 1):

It can be clearly seen that while the optimizer performed OR-expansion on your query (`VW_ORE_*****`), it was unable to perform it in your `CREATE TABLE` `DDL` statement. I could not find any official reference to this, but it seems that OR-expansion is not performed on the top level in a CTAS.

You could try the below:

```
 CREATE TABLE DUMMY_SCHEMA.DUMMY_TABLE AS
    WITH G as (
    SELECT /*+ materialize */ * FROM
        PRODUCTION.VERY_SMALL_TABLE L
        INNER JOIN PRODUCTION.BIG_PARTITIONED_TABLE_WITH_LOCAL_INDEX R
        on R.ID_1 = L.ID or R.ID_2 = L.ID
    )
    SELECT * FROM G;
```

Here is a simplified example if your case:

```
create table t1 (id1 number not null, id2 number not null);
insert into t1 select rownum, rownum + 1000000 from dual connect by level <= 1000000;
commit;
create index t1_id1 on t1(id1);
create index t1_id2 on t1(id2);
create table t2 (id number not null);
insert into t2 select rownum from dual connect by level <= 5;
insert into t2 select rownum + 1000000 from dual connect by level <= 5;
commit;
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'T1');
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'T2');
```

Then (as my tables are different than yours, I needed to set this to achieve similar results to yours and avoid B-tree index bitmap plans):

```
alter session set "_b_tree_bitmap_plans"=false;
```

Now the query (OR-expansion is performed, uses both indexes):

```
SQL> select t1.id1, t1.id2, t2.id from t1 join t2 on (t1.id1 = t2.id or t1.id2 = t2.id);

       ID1        ID2         ID
---------- ---------- ----------
         1    1000001          1
         2    1000002          2
         3    1000003          3
         4    1000004          4
         5    1000005          5
         1    1000001    1000001
         2    1000002    1000002
         3    1000003    1000003
         4    1000004    1000004
         5    1000005    1000005

10 rows selected.

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL_ID  5ax9k9jpjczk9, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select t1.id1, t1.id2, t2.id from t1 join t2 on (t1.id1 = t2.id or
t1.id2 = t2.id)

Plan hash value: 2262899810

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |                 |       |       |    66 (100)|          |
|   1 |  VIEW                          | VW_ORE_5133193F |    18 |   702 |    66   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   UNION-ALL                    |                 |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                |                 |    10 |   160 |    33   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS               |                 |    10 |   160 |    33   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL         | T2              |    10 |    50 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN          | T1_ID1          |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T1              |     1 |    11 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |    NESTED LOOPS                |                 |     8 |   128 |    33   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |     NESTED LOOPS               |                 |    10 |   128 |    33   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  10 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL         | T2              |    10 |    50 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 11 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN          | T1_ID2          |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 12 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T1              |     1 |    11 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   6 - access("T1"."ID1"="T2"."ID")
  11 - access("T1"."ID2"="T2"."ID")
  12 - filter(LNNVL("T1"."ID1"="T2"."ID"))

Note
-----
   - this is an adaptive plan
```

CTAS:

```
SQL> create table t5 as with g as (select t1.id1, t1.id2, t2.id from t1 join t2 on (t1.id1 = t2.id or t1.id2 = t2.id)) select * from g;

Table created.

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL_ID  cafkj1bahx8hu, child number 0
-------------------------------------
create table t5 as with g as (select t1.id1, t1.id2, t2.id from t1 join
t2 on (t1.id1 = t2.id or t1.id2 = t2.id)) select * from g

Plan hash value: 2652785614

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                        | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | CREATE TABLE STATEMENT           |      |       |       |  6268 (100)|          |
|   1 |  LOAD AS SELECT                  | T5   |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   OPTIMIZER STATISTICS GATHERING |      |    20 |   320 |  6267   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                  |      |    20 |   320 |  6267   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL            | T2   |    10 |    50 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL            | T1   |     2 |    22 |   626   (3)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   5 - filter(("T1"."ID1"="T2"."ID" OR "T1"."ID2"="T2"."ID"))
```

No OR-expansion, no indexes.

CTAS with CTE and `materialize` hint:

```
SQL> create table t4 as with g as (select /*+ materialize */ t1.id1, t1.id2, t2.id from t1 join t2 on (t1.id1 = t2.id or t1.id2 = t2.id)) select * from g;

Table created.

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL_ID  c80w81ckc4727, child number 1
-------------------------------------
create table t4 as with g as (select /*+ materialize */ t1.id1, t1.id2,
t2.id from t1 join t2 on (t1.id1 = t2.id or t1.id2 = t2.id)) select *
from g

Plan hash value: 653110608

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                | Name                      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | CREATE TABLE STATEMENT                   |                           |       |       |    73 (100)|          |
|   1 |  TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION               |                           |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   LOAD AS SELECT (CURSOR DURATION MEMORY)| SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6722_A1FFB3 |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    VIEW                                  | VW_ORE_5133193F           |    18 |   558 |    68   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     UNION-ALL                            |                           |       |       |            |          |
|   5 |      NESTED LOOPS                        |                           |    10 |   160 |    33   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |       NESTED LOOPS                       |                           |    10 |   160 |    33   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL                 | T2                        |    10 |    50 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | T1_ID1                    |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID        | T1                        |     1 |    11 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  10 |      NESTED LOOPS                        |                           |     8 |   128 |    33   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  11 |       NESTED LOOPS                       |                           |    10 |   128 |    33   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  12 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL                 | T2                        |    10 |    50 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 13 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | T1_ID2                    |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 14 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID        | T1                        |     1 |    11 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  15 |   LOAD AS SELECT                         | T4                        |       |       |            |          |
|  16 |    OPTIMIZER STATISTICS GATHERING        |                           |    18 |   702 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  17 |     VIEW                                 |                           |    18 |   702 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  18 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                   | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6722_A1FFB3 |    18 |   558 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   8 - access("T1"."ID1"="T2"."ID")
  13 - access("T1"."ID2"="T2"."ID")
  14 - filter(LNNVL("T1"."ID1"="T2"."ID"))
```

OR-expansion is performed, indexes are used. Note that you need the `materialize` hint, without it, it behaves the same as the original CTAS:

```
SQL> create table t5 as with g as (select t1.id1, t1.id2, t2.id from t1 join t2 on (t1.id1 = t2.id or t1.id2 = t2.id)) select * from g;

Table created.

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL_ID  cafkj1bahx8hu, child number 0
-------------------------------------
create table t5 as with g as (select t1.id1, t1.id2, t2.id from t1 join
t2 on (t1.id1 = t2.id or t1.id2 = t2.id)) select * from g

Plan hash value: 2652785614

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                        | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | CREATE TABLE STATEMENT           |      |       |       |  6268 (100)|          |
|   1 |  LOAD AS SELECT                  | T5   |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   OPTIMIZER STATISTICS GATHERING |      |    20 |   320 |  6267   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                  |      |    20 |   320 |  6267   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL            | T2   |    10 |    50 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL            | T1   |     2 |    22 |   626   (3)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   5 - filter(("T1"."ID1"="T2"."ID" OR "T1"."ID2"="T2"."ID"))
```

Comment: thank you very much, yes it works! using materialize hit. what do "this_b_tree_bitmap_plans"  exactly?

Comment: @jimi It disables B-tree bitmap plans, where b-tree index rowids are converted to bitmaps, and after bitmap operations they are converted back to rowids.